# The "button".config() doesn't work in my code

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

So, i tried to refresh a label by pressing a button with the .config() command and it doesn't work at all. I don't have any idea how to make it work properly. (It should be as simple as possible)

```
def points():
    global mode,score,show_score
    if mode==0:
        score=0
    else:
        score=score+1
    if score==1:
        show_score=Label(root,text=("Score:",score))
        show_score.pack()

def refresh_score():
    global show_score
    show_score.config(root,text=("Score:",score))`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify what library you are using in the future (I think it's tkinter?) as well as provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What "isn't working"? Is there an error? Are things not displaying how you would like?

Don't pass the root window to the `.config` method. The `.config` method acts on the object right before the `.` so it already knows all the meta-data about that object.

The value for the `text` keyword argument in `show_score.config` doesn't look correct. First, you might need to declare `score` as a global variable within `refresh_score` just like you did in `points`. Second, you are trying to set the `text` keyword argument equal to a tuple containing a string and an integer however it should be just one string. Try `text = "Score: " + str(score)` instead. You should also change this where you define `show_score` as well: `show_score = Label(root, text = "Score: " + str(score))`